# Looping horizontally sliding divs infinitly

Tags: jquery, slideshow, infinite-loop, horizontal-scrolling

I have been trying to write my own carousal with infinite loop. The code works perfectly fine with one exception. I want to it go in loop where first divs gets appended in the last and so on. Right now it gets reset to previous position.

I have tried different things but none seems to work. Any help?

```
let divArray = $(".mybox");
let sliderFrame = $(".slider");
let i = 0;

function test() {
  //sliderFrame.append(divArray[i]);
  sliderFrame.delay(1000).animate({ right: 150 * i + "px" });
  if (i < divArray.length/2) i++;
  else i = 0;
  test();
}
test();

https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/mLYdeb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this --

```
let sliderFrame = $(".slider");
let i = 0;

function test() {
  let divArray = $(".mybox");
  $(divArray[0]) 
    .animate({"margin-left":"-150px"}, 5000, function() {
    $(this)
      .css({"width":"150px","margin-left":"0px"})
      .appendTo(sliderFrame);
    test();
  });
}
test();
```